# How to bundle React + Flask app to Windows executable?

Tags: python, reactjs, electron

I have a React frontend and Flask backend which has SQL lite.
I want to bundle it for desktop executable.

I tried electron JS but it is making frontend exe only. I have to start flask backend separately.
Want to bundle both so that client does not need to install python on his pc.

Is there any way to start flask server inside main.js file (Electron js template) !?
or combine both react + flask (with sql lite) into windows exe with any tech ?